# Merging 2 branches in one of the two or in a new branch

Tags: git, merge

Lets say I am on a branch `test-a` and I create two new branches from `a` and do some individual commits to each one(to different files in each branch):

```
#in branch test-a
$git checkout test-a

#creating branch test-b and push a commit
$git checkout -b test-b
$git commit -a -m "initial commit in test-b"
$git push

#creating branch test-b and push a commit
$git checkout test-a
$git checkout -b test-c
$git commit -a -m "initial commit in test-c"
$git push
```

Now how can I merge `test-b` with `test-c` in one branch, either `test-b` or `test-c` or in a new branch `merged-b-c` branch? (not merged with `test-a`)

this is the usage of `merge` command in my case?:

```
$git checkout test-b
$git merge test-c
```

Comment: You don't help by just giving a negative vote and not explaining the reason. consider to comment the reason for negative vote.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Yes, you would just use `git merge` here. Is the command at the end not doing what you want, or are you just asking us whether that is the correct thing to do? Why don’t you just try it?

Comment: I was asking if its the correct usage of `merge` in that case. Or there is a better way that ppl are using, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want the changes in a separate branch, then just fork out a new one from one of them, and the merge the another.

```
git checkout test-b
git checkout -b test-b-c
git merge test-c
```

Otherwise, if you don't mind updating the existing branches, the way you have merged would work too. As an additional pointer, if you are individually using the branch, and want to maintain linear history you can use `rebase` too.

```
git checkout test-b
git rebase test-c
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand you...

You have three branches. branch A, branch B and branch C.

Your "main" branch is A, and you don't want to merge anything with this branch for now.

You work on branch B, then, on branch C. And you want to merge branch B with C.

You can do what you say in your post.

```
$git checkout test-b
$git merge test-c
```

This is absolute the common merge usage.